# evaluation order initialization array in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, array-initialization

I like c++11 variadic templates, so I often write some little codes with it.

See this example:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>

template< typename ... T >
auto make_vector(T ... t ) -> std::vector< typename std::common_type<T...>::type >
{
    std::vector< typename  std::common_type<T...>::type > v;
    v.reserve( sizeof...(T) );

    using list = int[];
    (void)list{ 0, ( (void)v.push_back(std::move(t)) ,0)... };
    //                |/ / / /
    //                --------
    //                 \-- How are evaluated v.push_back()s, sequentially or arbitrary ?
    return v;
}

int main()
{
    auto v = make_vector(2, 3.0, 'a', 7UL );

    for(auto e : v )
      printf("%.2lf ", e);

    printf("\n");

}
```

**Q: Is evaluation order of initialization of array   sequentially or arbitrary (or implementation defined, undefined behavior) ?**

If `make_vector`  is wrong, how me fix its?

Comment: @Khurshid: +1 for the question. As an aside, why `push_back`? Why not construct the vector directly? `return {std::forward<typename std::common_type<T...>::type>(t)...};`

Comment: @GMan: Nope, braced-init-lists are specifically sequenced left-to-right, even if that evaluates to a normal constructor call. It has also always been left-to-right for aggregate initialization.

Comment: @Xeo: Read it as a function call for some reason, my mistake!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

They are evaluated sequentially. C++11 § 8.5.4 [dcl.init.list] paragraph 4:

> Within the *initializer-list* of a *braced-init-list*, the *initializer-clauses*, including any that result from pack
>   expansions (14.5.3), are evaluated in the order in which they appear.

Given that `vector` has an `initializer_list` constructor, you could simplify your function to:

```
template <typename ... T>
auto make_vector(T ... t) ->
  std::vector< typename std::common_type<T...>::type >
{
  return { static_cast<typename std::common_type<T...>::type>(t)... };
}
```

and not have to worry about arcane initialization semantics ;)

Comment: Using `std::forward` you can do away with the cast too :)

Comment: C11 http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p23 - The evaluations of the initialization list expressions are indeterminately sequenced with respect to one another and thus the order in which any side effects occur is unspecified.